# select first element in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat populating li tag. I want by default first element should be clicked and a function should be fired. how can I do this using ng-repeated. I tried ng-if and ng-switch. but other than first element rest are not getting populated.

html:

```
<ul id = "colors">
    <li ng-repeat="color in colors | filter:query" >
        <div style="background-color : {{color.color}}; height : 20px; width : 20px;" ng-if = '$first' ng-click="getViewsByColors(color)">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Your click event will not trigger in that manner.
According to the doc

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat. You should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

Your snippet will look like

```
<div style="background-color : {{color.color}}; height : 20px; width : 20px;" ng-init="($first) ? getViewsByColors(color) : ''">
```

It will execute the `getViewsByColors` function for first iteration of your array/object. You don't need to use `ng-if` in this case. It will not work for the rest of your values.
`

Comment: thanks @vineet but still on loading this page this function is not getting called. i tried defining function on chrome console.

Comment: Have you declared this function on your controller scope ? Will you please share more code or create a fiddle ?

Comment: hey sorry vineet... my mistake name of function was wrong. getting it now... thnaks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. The function get invoked, but the first items is not being marked as selected.

Comment: Hey I figured it out myself. Please update your answer, it might help someone else

`<li ng-class="($first) ? 'active' : ' ' "> `